# java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed) in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

When I run a distributed test with JMeter, I get the following error on some slave clients. For this reason, for example, if I send 10000 requests, only 5000 requests go.

```
2023-02-07 17:35:55,125 ERROR o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: sampleOccurred
java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217) ~[?:?]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.processBatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender.sampleOccurred(BatchSampleSender.java:182) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender.sampleOccurred(DataStrippingSampleSender.java:106) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.sampleOccurred(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:94) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:58) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:1037) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:591) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1883) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1921) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1582) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:352) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.marshalValue(UnicastRef.java:293) ~[?:?]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:155) ~[?:?]
    ... 12 more
```

I looked in the etc/ssh/ssh_config settings but it doesn't seem to be because of it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JMeter slaves cannot report results back to master due to networking issues. If you're using [SSH tunnels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol#Secure_Shell_tunneling) for establishing the connectivity you might want to check SSH server logs for any suspicious entries.

From JMeter perspective you can check the following:

1. [RMI ports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) which are used for bi-directional communication should be open and accessible
2. You can also play with [batching properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) like `num_sample_threshold` and `asynch.batch.queue.size` and try to setting it to lower value so sending results would occur more often and the size of the chunk would be less.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I was sending it with a 4MB size attachment. And I guess I'm getting an error because I'm sending it in base64.

Comment: Unless you modified `mode` property JMeter slaves should only send statistical results to master, no request or response data should be there.